# Why the flexbox items are not looking center and the border-bottom is not covering the whole space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a complete beginner in web development so please excuse me if my question seems to be foolish.

- After learning about the `flexbox` concept I tried to apply the concept for developing a simple header. Everything was going perfect but then even after using `align-items:center` property the items are not looking perfectly centred.
- Then I tried to use the border-bottom for the `nav-main` class to give an underline but I don't understand why the underline is not covering the whole space.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading {
  order: 2;
}

.nav-main {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  order: 1;
}

.nav-main li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <h1 class="heading">The Peace</h1>
  <nav class="nav-main">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

***Edit***
My first problem is solved by the following code but the **underline** problem still remains the same.

```
.nav-main ul{
padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved both the problems by using only one flexbox with text-alignment option as follows:

```css
*{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

html, body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.mainContainer{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: lemonchiffon;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.heading{
order:2;
}

ul{
padding: 0;
}

.nav-main {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
order:1;
}
.nav-main li{
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trialStyle.css">
</head>
<body>

   
<div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="heading">The Peace</h1>
    <nav class="nav-main">
        <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set .nav-main ul padding to 0:

```css
* {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: lemonchiffon;
align-items: center;
}

.heading {
order: 2;
}

.nav-main {
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
order: 1;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.nav-main ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-main li {
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="heading">The Peace</h1>
    <nav class="nav-main">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Although it's working but you used two flexboxes kindly check my answer below I tried to play with text alignment and everything is great now only with one flexbox

Answer (score 1):

For the underline problem you need set the width of nav-main as 100% and those flexbox values

```
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Your content properties in the li in the ul doesn't align perfectly because you gave it a margin of 5px and this makes the rightmost li to be shifted by 5px to the right. Try to make your ul also a flexbox and give it a justify-content property of space-evenly...

Answer (score 0):

**RESULT:**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}


.nav-main {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  order: 1;  
}

.heading {
  order: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

 .nav-main li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
} 

.nav-main ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="heading">The Peace</h1>

    <nav class="nav-main">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```